# Weird files appearing in my home folder

Tags: 11.04, files

For a few weeks / months now I keep discovering weird files in my home folder. They are named, for example, like this:
"5C9543D4B30452FD64A2D60D7DFB8CE6ABD677B2.14.0.794.0_service_ipc". Its a 0 byte file of the type "socket (inode/socket)".

Any ideas where this could come from? I'm deleting them every now and then, but they keep appearing again...

My guess would be something like tomcat or mysql creates the file, but both were turned off using chkconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Google Chrome or Chromium?

Chrome and Chromium are using file names like this as the names of their UNIX-Domain socket files for inter-process communication.

If by accident you are using Chrome version 14.04.794 then you know where this part of the file name comes from.

Comment: Good catch! ;) Yep, I'm using Chrome 14.04.794. So, is this Chrome's default behavior?

Comment: The code is called for various purposes. One of them is Cloud printing - did you enable that?

Comment: Yep, Cloud Printing is enabled.

Comment: As long as the service process is running (you find it with "ps -fe | fgrep type=service"), even when no Chrome window is open, the file has a "right to exist". Once the service process is killed ideally it should take care of removing this file. If it does not you might consider making a bug report or comment on this issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85088

Comment: It's a little strange to create such files in a user's home directory. At least they could hide it...

However, if Chrome really needs it I'm fine with it.